# Trying to import project from SVN in new workspace

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to import project in eclipse from SVN and getting following error:
*RA layer request failed.
Could not read chunk size: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

If i am creating a new workspace, then only i am getting this error. If using old workspace, no error.

Comment: Check your antivirus or firewall.

Comment: I am working on VDI, and no issue from firewall side